# How to use tmap with shiny

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, tmap

I am having issues getting a map using tmap to load in shiny. When I run the shiny code, the input sections show up, but not the output. The code doesn't crash, but it also never finishes running. My goal is to be able to have an interactive map using `tmap` and `leaflet`, which has been able to run outside of shiny.

```
library(tmap) # and maybe also: library(tmaptools)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Europe"),

  mainPanel(
    plotOutput(outputId = "europe")))

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$europe <- renderPlot({
    qtm(Europe)})}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2):

All works for me:

```
library(shiny)
library(tmap)
data("Europe")

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Europe"),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput(outputId = "europe")))

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$europe <- renderPlot({
    qtm(Europe)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: What versions of R, shiny, and tmap are you using? Could those affect the performance?

Comment: I'm on R version 3.3.2 and just downloaded the `tmap` from CRAN so on `1.11-2`. In not sure about performance, I have a powerful machine with 64GB Ram

Comment: Using your code made the map load into the shiny window, but the code doesn't finish loading. Any suggestions?